# Acting on post-failure only if the job has not regressed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I want to implement the following notifications in my declarative pipeline:

> (regression) → Job has started to fail!
>
> (failure) → Job is still failing.
>
> (fixed) → Job has resumed.

It doesn't seem like `post`'s [conditions](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) can do this. Instead, when a build fails, both `failure` and `regression` trigger. There's a `changed` condition, but I think what this task wants is `unchanged { failure }`, which doesn't exist.

```
post {
    regression {
        slackSend message: 'Job has started to fail!'
    }
    failure {
        slackSend message: 'Job is still failing.'
    }
    fixed {
        slackSend message: 'Job has resumed.'
    }  // no need for 'success' as we don't want a notification while it's working
}
```

The above config will send the following notifications, if the job previously succeeded:

> (job fails)
>
> > Job has started to fail!
> >
> > Job is still failing.
>
> (job fails)
>
> > Job is still failing.
>
> (job succeeds)
>
> > Job has resumed.

There's that extra "Job is still failing" message when the job first starts to fail. Is there a way around this using `post` conditions?

Alternatively, how can I implement this behaviour another way? I've made a pass at `post { always { // decide which message is appropriate } }`, but haven't figured out how to identify the previous build's status.